# Add lib dependencies to Axis2 web service when generating aar file

Tags: web-services, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-integration-studio

I've created an Axis2 Service Project with Developer Studio 3.7.1.
The structure of the project is the following:

```
ProjectName
-->\src
---->\main
------>\java
-------->Source Code of the web service
------>\resources
-------->\META-INF
---------->services.xml
-->\lib
-->Jar dependencies of the web service
```

From the Project Explorer, when I right-click in the project and select "Export Project as Deployable Archive" to generate the aar file, it not contains the lib with the dependencies and I have to add them by hand before deploy the aar to the Axis2 server repository.
My question is how can be added those dependencies automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your lib directory under ProjectName/src/main/resources will package your lib into aar file.